# Scipy -Numpy: Calculate integral of Joint Probability density

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, integral, probability-density

**A bit of background**

I am using the emd package in python to decompose a time series into IMF's. I then want to estimate the Marginal-Hilbert Spectrum.

According to the original paper by Huang

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.4211.pdf

The marginal Hibert spectrum is given by:

[image]

, where Ai is the amplitude and phase time series of mode i.
the joint probability density function (pdf) P(ω, A) of the frequency [ωi] and amplitude [Ai], which are extracted from all modes i = 1 · · · N together.

**In this case, could someone indicate how I could perform the integral given the two 1-D arrays IA, IF?**

```
### For minimum reproducible example  
import emd
### Define functions
def hilb(signal,fs, unwrap=False):
    from scipy.signal import hilbert
    analytic_signal = hilbert(signal)
    A               = np.abs(analytic_signal)
    i_p             = np.unwrap(np.angle(analytic_signal))
    i_f             = np.diff(i_p) /(2.0*np.pi) * fs
    return  A,i_f

### Define parameters
dt    = 1
fs    = 1/dt
B     = np.sin(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,1000))+0.05*np.random.rand(1000)
T     = dt*len(B)     ### Length of signal
nbins = 200

## Get IMF's
imf = emd.sift.sift(B)



inst_freq = np.zeros((len(imf)-1,len(imf.T)))
inst_amp = np.zeros((len(imf)-1,len(imf.T)))
for i in range(len(imf.T)):
    ### Calculate instantaneous frequencies (IF) 
    ### and instantaneous amplitudes (IA)
    
    inst_amp1, inst_f1 = hilb(imf.T[i],fs, unwrap=True)
    inst_amp[:,i]    = inst_amp1[1:]
    inst_freq[:,i]   = inst_f1

### End of code required for minimum reproducible example####   

### Collapse the arrays into 1d, make easier to use     
IA_flat = np.ravel(inst_amp)
IF_flat1 = np.ravel(inst_freq)
IF_flat = IF_flat1[IF_flat1>0]
IA_flat = IA_flat[IF_flat1>0]
```

**My way of trying to estimate the integral. Probably wrong?**

```
# 1st step create a Joint probability density function 

# Doing it with log space is probably wrong? Becaus trapezoid integration assumes dA = constant?

#IA_bins = np.logspace(np.log10(min(IA_flat)),np.log10(max(IA_flat)),nbins)
#IF_bins = np.logspace(np.log10(min(IF_flat[IF_flat>0])),np.log10(max(IF_flat[IF_flat>0])),nbins)
IA_b  = np.linspace((min(IA_flat[IF_flat>0])),(max(IA_flat[IF_flat>0])),nbins)
IF_b  = np.linspace((min(IF_flat[IF_flat>0])),(max(IF_flat[IF_flat>0])),nbins)
p_out = plt.hist2d(IF_flat[IF_flat>0],IA_flat[IF_flat>0],bins=[IA_bins,IF_bins],density=True)
plt.clf()

### Get 1) Probability density 2) Edges in x axis 3) Edges in y axis
Pjoint,f_edges, A_edges =p_out[0],p_out[1],p_out[2]


### So you can plot later, not needed for integration
f_centers = (0.5)*np.diff(f_edges) + f_edges[:-1]



h =[]
for i in range(len(f_centers)):
    index = np.where((IF_flat>f_edges[i]) & (IF_flat<f_edges[i+1]))[0].astype(int)
    H     = np.nanmean(IA_flat[index]**2)
    P     = Pjoint[i]
    P     = P[P>0]
    h.append(np.trapz(P*H))

    
h = np.array(h)


plt.loglog(f_centers[h>0],h[h>0],label=r'$Marginal\ Hilbert \ Transform$')
```

Any Idea of how I could estimate the integral shown in the beginning?